# Approximation of semicontinuous functions by continuous (or smooth) functions with closed form

Tags: approximation-theory, closed-form-expressions, semicontinuity

I'm looking for a sequence $(f_{\epsilon})_{\epsilon>0}$ of continuous (or smooth) functions approximating a semicontinuous function $f$.
Here, for approximation, pointwise convergence is fine.
For the function $f$, it is enough for me to be such as $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, that is, it is bounded from above or below.

I know that there is such a sequence of approximation functions (Beire's characteristic theorem).
However, I need a closed form of $f_{\epsilon}$ because I keep in mind a certain differential equation and have to understand an equation $f_{\epsilon}$ satisfies.
(If possible, I want ones to preserve the form of equation although I think that it is not realistic.)
Unfortunately I know only the so-called inf/sup-convolution, that is, the form of
$$
f_{\epsilon}(x)=\inf_{y\in A}f(y)-\frac{d^2(x,y)}{\epsilon}\quad\text{$A$:set, $d$:distance function},
$$
and mollification by Friedrichs mollifier, and these approximation does not work for my equation and I didn't find other forms.

If you know, I'm glad if you tell me that.

---

**More precisely my situation**: (This is a part of my target (proof of **Comparison principle**))

Fix a point $x\in(0,1]$.
Let $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be respectively a upper- and lower semicontinuous functions such that $(f-g)(x)>(f-g)(z)$ for all $z\in[0,x)$, $(x_{j},y_{j})\in(0,1]^{2}$ be a sequence such that $(x_j,y_j)\to (x,x)$ and $\delta_j>0$ be a constant such that $\delta_j\to0$.
If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, I'm in a situation to be able to prove that, if the inequality
$$
\int_{0}^{x_{j}-\delta}\frac{f(x_{j}-\delta)-f(z)}{(x_{j}-z)^{3/2}}dz-\int_{0}^{y_{j}-\delta}\frac{g(y_{j}-\delta)-g(z)}{(y_{j}-z)^{3/2}}dz\ge0.
$$
holds for sufficiently large $j$, then $f\le g$ in $[0,1]$.
Indeed, since the inequality involving integral is guaranteed by the dominated convergence theorem, I can get $f\le g$ (this relationship is what I want the most). Thus, I expect that, if I can approximate $f$ and $g$ by continuous functions so that the inequality involving integral holds again, then I obtain $f\le g$ for approximate functions and hence limiting yields also for semiconitnuous functions.

Comment: What metric on functions are you using?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Euclidean distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is fine beacause I consider only in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Comment: I am asking what is the metric on the *function space*, not on the domain and the codomain of the functions. Are you using the supremum norm, or $L^1$ norm, or $L^2$ norm, or what?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Ah, I'm sorry. It's the supremum norm.

Comment: Once you have continuous functions, you can approximate these by polynomials to obtain "closed form" functions.

Comment: I don't get what use of supremum norm you mean… A semicontinuous function is Baire-class one, point-wise limit of continuous functions, but of course not uniform, unless it's itself continuous. In what norm or topology you want to approximate the semicontinuous function?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, I know. But, I think it's not realistic to use "polynomial form" for differential equations. I'm sorry if I mistake.

Comment: @PietroMajer & AndrejBauer I thought I had wrote a topology in my question, sorry. And the supremum norm is a mistake. I'm sorry. (I wonder why the wrote...) It enough for me to know a sequence of continuous functions which converges pointwise to an original function.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, I guess a sequence $f_\epsilon$ is not more explicit/close form than the function $f$ itself. So your requirements would be clearer if you  add some information on the function $f$, and on the differential equation. Why the approximations you mentioned are not satisfying to you, and  what would you like to have on the $f_\epsilon$ besides point-wise convergence to $f$? What about additional convergence or just boundedness other in senses like e.g.  $L^p$ ?

Comment: @PietroMajer I added a new information in my question. As you say, I might be not able to expect to get a closed form. But I want if possible altough I pobably should consider the oher way.

Comment: Have you tried regularizing using convolution, i.e.  $f_\epsilon = f * g_\epsilon$ with $g_\epsilon$ e.g. Gaussian random variable with variance $\epsilon$ (i.e., $g_\epsilon(x) =(2\pi \epsilon)^{-1/2} \exp( -(|x|^2)/2\epsilon))$?

Comment: @user75274 I havn't it. only mollifier for convolution type. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you directly adapt your proof of $f\le g$ to semicontinuous functions? In any case, for discontinuous functions you want to prove $f\le g$ **a.e.** right?

Comment: @PietroMajer I can't adapt for semicontinuous functions because the proof (I have now) strongly depends on the continuity of functions. Yes, $f\le g$ a.e. is fine.